# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter : while running Mapreduce job

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I am running MR program in my cluster. I made sure I have correct class path exported. But I still see the error. I have followed the following steps to run this program.

1)

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/etc/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/*.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5.2.0.6.0-101.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:.:
```

2)

```
hadoop jar /XMLAnalytics/Appcode/MR/XMLload.jaredm.bigdata.hadoop.xmlanalytics.stagingprocess.SplitXMLProcessDriver/XMLAnalytics/Input/TestData/Claims/SPLIT_CLAIM_FOLDER_WORK.xml/XMLAnalytics/Staging/Output/TestData/Claims/ 123 pega Claims
```

## Error:

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:721)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:129)
>           ... 7 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter
>           at edm.bigdata.hadoop.xmlanalytics.stagingprocess.SplitXMLProcessMapper.(SplitXMLProcessMapper.java:49)
>           ... 12 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           ... 13 more

```
echo `hbase classpath`
```

> /usr/lib/hbase/bin/../conf:/usr/java/default/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/..:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/asm-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-math-2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-framework-2.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-http-2.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-http-server-2.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-rcm-2.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-client-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-common-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-common-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-examples-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-it-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-it-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-prefix-tree-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-protocol-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-server-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-server-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-shell-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-testing-util-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-thrift-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/htrace-core-2.01.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/httpclient-4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.servlet-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-test-framework-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jettison-1.3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/libthrift-0.9.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/metrics-core-2.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/zookeeper.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*:/etc/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/*.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5.2.0.6.0-101.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*:/etc/hadoop/conf:/*:/lib/*:/usr/lib/zookeeper/*:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/*: